# Is there a way to control system volume?

Tags: react-native, expo

i'm trying to make a simple app to learn react-native/expo.
After hours of research I finally decided to ask you for your help, is there a way to manage system volume with expo ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it within Expo, Expo playback is bound by system Audio settings. See: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/av/#playback-status

> Note that volume and isMuted only affect the audio of this playbackObject and do NOT affect the system volume.

You may want to look at https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting/tree/master/ios

Comment: So I will have to do without expo this time, thanks you !